# How do you create a Jinja list and collect a Jinja list in the flask app?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I can make a list and get it, but it only gives me one of those items in the list, if I try to get any others outside of the first index I get the list index out of range exception

The list I've tried to make (the only thing I've found online).

```
{% set infoList = [1,2] %}
<form method="post"><button name="add_to_collection" value={{infoList}}>{{collection[0]}}</button></form>
```

The way I've tried to collect the list

```
information = request.form.getlist('information')
```

When I try to get both indexes 0 & 1, I get List Out Of Index Range, I can only get the first.
If I print out that list, this is the output

```
[1,
```

not sure how this works and couldn't find it online anywhere.

Comment: Please show your HTML as well

Comment: sorry, i noticed right after I posted it. I added the form as well. was there anything else I needed for the HTML? i can't see anything else that would matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need to escape the comma. If you inspect the button you'll see this:

```
<button name="add_to_collection" value="[1," 2]="">text here</button>
```

Here, it thinks you're adding two things to the html. I'm honestly not sure if you can set an input value as a list.

Try this:

```
{% set infoList = "[1,2]" %}
```

or this:

```
<button name="add_to_collection" value="{{ infoList }}">{{collection[0]}}</button>
```

or even this if the list never changes:

```
<button name="add_to_collection" value="[1,2]">{{collection[0]}}</button>
```

and then deal with turning it back into a list when you're in the backend.

Comment: yeah i guess i'll resort to that. there is a request.form.getlist() so I figured it would work.

Comment: Either solution is fine. The other solution is overly complex for your needs. If this list you are using is static, mine is fine and will load faster, (fastest would just be to add the list directly into the value setting as text). If the list will be dynamic, you should use the other solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should enclose the attributes in quotes. If you also pass the values of the list separated by commas, it is easy to query the values on the server side and to convert the type.

```
{% set info_list = [1,2] %}
<form method="post">
    <button name="info" value="{{info_list | join(',')}}">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
info = request.form.get('info', type=lambda x: [int(t) for t in x.split(',')])
```

Comment: this makes sense. though I'm confused. whats the post of request.form.getlist() if you can't actually get lists? you just have to send a string and convert it?

Comment: `request.form.getlist(...)` is for multiple elements with the same name attribute.

Comment: oh i see. that contradicts another stackoverflow post. thanks for the info!